# Request encryption over https?

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

In HTTPS (SSL) browser send the encrypted data which can be Decrypted by  server only.

To confirm it, i did set up the burp proxy on my Firefox browser so that it intercepts the request sent to HTTPS server by browser .
When i receive it at burp, i see the data as entered by user though i was expecting browser must have encrypted that but did not.

So at what point of time browser encrypt data over HTTPS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most pieces of software that do this (e.g. Anti-virus scanners) replace the https certificate with their own so the https traffic can be man-in-the-middled by the software.

While I'm not familiar with Burp, it looks like it does the same: https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_using.html

So instead of

> browser --(via https)--> server

Which only the server could read as only the server has the private key to decrypt the http so, it becomes:

> browser --(via https)--> burp -- (via https)--> server

If you look at the https cert in your browser you'll probably notice it's been issued by Burp rather than being the real cert that the site shows when not using Burp.

This is the only real way of doing this, without majorly changing the browser to intercept it before the encryption happens, but can create its own problems: Should software really intercept traffic between you and your bank? What if that first connection can be compromised (see [the Lenovo superfish incident](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfish#Lenovo_incident) for example). Many people (myself included) dislike MITM https services for this reason.

Comment: Thanks BazzaDP. You mean to say that temporariliy  when browser sends request to https server via burp , burp acts as server to browser. Also burp acts as client to actual https server. Npe burps receives the certificate from actual https server but it keeps that with itself and sends its own certificate to browser and tells browser not to encrypt any data. Right ?

Comment: Almost - except for last bit. The browser traffic IS still encrypted, but it's encrypted with burps fake certificate created for that site, rather than with the real certificate that site would normally send. This allows burp to read the traffic (since it knows the key for the fake cert) but still allows the site to look encrypted (green padlock) and all https links to still work. Burp then re-encrypts it with the real cert before sending it out across the Internet. As I say, not used burp myself, but this is the way it normally works. Check the cert in browser with burp enabled to be sure.

Comment: And sorry meant to include the link to Burp documentation in my original answer but see I forgot to. Added it now.